# How to move and animate a image in android?

Tags: android, animation, imageview

i m trying to move a image in the imageview from top to bottom and back..but the image seems to stay on the place and not move at all. i tried the animation type but it didnt work..here is the code..

```
    setContentView(R.layout.game);
    AnimationSet set=new AnimationSet(true);
    Animation animation=new TranslateAnimation(0,2000,0,1220);
    ImageView img =new ImageView(this);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.dig);
    animation.setDuration(3000);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    set.addAnimation(animation);
    set.startNow();
```